# why does my output is wrong in exponents in java

Tags: java

why is it that this is wrong? i input the heightL as 2 the output must be 4 but there is something wrong

```
class He{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int heightL=2;
    int a = 9;
    System.out.println(Math.abs(a));
    System.out.println(2^(heightL));
}
}
```

why is it that the output in the second part is 0?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm

Comment: A fast way to do 2 to the power of is either `1L << x` for a long or `Math.scaleb(1, x)` for a double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^` is not an exponent operator, it's bit-wise XOR (and 2 XOR 2 is 0).

For exponent, use `Math.pow(2,heightL)`.

Comment: sir why is it possible loss of precision.?

Comment: @Hello23 Where do you see `possible loss of precision`?

Comment: thank you sir its already working..